# How to do a manual injection in the angular jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, dependency-injection, jasmine

In the app.module.ts, I have CustomInterceptor like below.

**App.module.ts**

```
.
.
Provider: [{
  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, 
  useClass: CustomInterceptor,
  Multi:true
 }],
.
.
```

Test.component.spec.ts

```
  TestBed.configureTestingModule([{
   provider: {
     provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, 
     useClass: CustomInterceptor,
     multi:true 
   }
  }];
```

So this is what I tried;

```
     BeforeEach(inject([{
       provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, 
        useClass: CustomInterceptor,
        multi:true
      }],(interceptor)=>{
         interceptor =interceptor;
       })));

it('interceptor is created', () => {
  Expect(interceptor).toBeTrusty(); //error [[object] [object]] 
});
```

Is this the Correct way to inject custom token into test class?

**ANSWER:**

Just found my own solution. The whole injectable and injector concepts and how it are used are new to me, and finally I realise what is wrong with my code.

Instead of looking at `{provide: xxx, --:yyy}`, I should have looked at the `Injector`. [Reading](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers)

```
Before(inject([Injector, (injector: Injector) => {
 let cInterceptor = injector.get(HTTP_INTERCEPTORS); // find the token service in the provider register
 interceptor = cInterceptor.find(ci => ci instanceOf CustomInterceptor) as CustomInterceptor; // because of multiple, it stores as array and then convert it to the class we need it 
});
```

Comment: your code is so much invalid...

Comment: Can you be a bit of specific on this? Im on my mobile phone so autocapitalise is on, please excuse this, and I will fix this when I have access to internet on my laptop.